# Printing in Java - characters are too close together

Tags: java, graphics2d

I am using the class Graphics2D to print some texts from a Java application. To print it I am implementing the interface Printable and the class Graphics2D. Then I use the method drawString from Graphics2D.

The thing is that sometimes (depending on the string I am printing), some characters are on top of each other and the spacing between characters is crazy.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: A code sample, and perhaps a screenshot, would help us find your answer.

Comment: As for why, I guess different String could be overlapping, or possibly the font could be odd. You can use the:
g.setFont(new Font(String name, int mod, int size));

Comment: I noticed I had "kerning on". What is it anyway?

Comment: For better printable output, consider using a report writer library instead of Swing. Often it comes down to using the best tool for the job. You could easily integrate this with your current Swing application if needed.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969909/java-printing-quality-in-linux-on-dot-matrix-printer) mentions setting RenderingHints. Fractional metrics, anti-aliasing or **hinting** might be of use. You could try another font too.

Comment: Thumbed up because I forgot about rendering, rookie mistake :(

Answer (score -1):

For workaround of this issue Set the public static property RasterPrinterJob.shapeTextProp to true.

Comment: Can you detail more please?

Comment: @Robin before printing command `RasterPrinterJob.shapeTextProp = true;`